# Non-Binary Tree Insertion (not natural order) Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-structures

I am building a java web app (Spring Boot, MongoDB) and need to use a tree to structure some of the data. The web app will facilitate creating and reading adventure stories and each 'scene' in the story is a node in the tree leading to other nodes. Each node contains multiple Strings.

I have written a basic binary tree, but the recursive and automatic sorting nature of binary trees doesn't seem to work here and any node can have 0-5 child nodes.

How do I add a new node? If I were just putting this all in one class I could add each one, but this is a dynamic application where users will create and edit stories.

In a binary tree I can compare a value and it will automatically add it for me, but in this case, each node must be attached to specific parent nodes. Will I have to use an int or double of some sort?

I realize this is trivial to some, but nearly all the data I find on trees are for binary trees or naturally ordered trees.

Thanks for your time and resources!

As I cannot think of how to access a particular node to add another node to the List of childNodes, I don't have much code... Below is what I do have.

public class SceneNode {

```
@Id
private String storyId;

private String parentId;
private String option;
private String description;
private List<SceneNode> childNodes;

//constructors
public SceneNode() {};
public SceneNode(String parentId, String option, String descrtion) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.option = option;
    this.description = descrtion;
}

//methods
public void insert(String parentId, String option, String description) {
    SceneNode newScene = new SceneNode(parentId, option, description);
```

// getters setters . . .
}

public class StoryTree {

```
private SceneNode root;


//methods
public void insert(String parentId, String option, String description) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new SceneNode(parentId, option, description);
    } 
}
```

}

```
// getters & setters...
```

Comment: Please provide code examples. This is needed to help with your specific problem.

Comment: @bob0the0mighty, I added what I could. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it though so there isn't much code, just basic class fields.

Comment: @Dr.M - One approach is to have each node hold a map from reader choice to next node. One way to do that is to have each SceneNode hold a HashMap<String,SceneNode>. This leaves open the possibility of cycles in your story *graph*.

Comment: Possible solution:  The Insert method in node (SceneNode) just creates a new node and adds it to the List<SceneNode>.  It would be the insert method in the StoryTree class that is passed the node ID to add children node to as parameter, first finding that node in the tree, then running the insert method for that particular node.
// This means I'd need to first code a findNode(String id) method first AND need to either get an ID generated from MongoDB or generate within Java and pass to MongoDB. ??? thoughts

Comment: @AndyThomas, I really like the idea of using a HashMap and the potential for cyclic story lines, a feature I wanted, but wasn't sure how I would implement while keeping with the assignment of a "tree".

Comment: @Dr.M - A tree is a directed, acyclic graph. If your representation can support a graph, it can also support a tree. One type of tree is binary, but it's not the only type. One representation is for a node to hold other nodes as fields, but it's not the only representation. It's a reasonable representation for a node to hold a map of other nodes, but you are the best judge of whether your teacher will accept it. Another approach is parallel arrays or lists, one with user actions, one with corresponding nodes.